# How to set up media queries in my navbar to make it mobile responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my navbar with my logo on the left and the tabs on the right to be mobile responsive. The viewpoint meta tag drops my logo down below the nav tabs when in mobile view. It also has a scrolling function in javascript. Is it too late for me to go back in and add breakpoints with media queries? Is there an easy fix to this solution? I've tried everything and can not seem to make it work.

```css
.nav_bar {
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  color: rgb(78, 78, 78);
}

.nav_bar ul li a.active-page {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.nav_bar .nav_ {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.nav_bar .nav_ .item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.nav_bar .nav_ .item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.nav_bar .logo {
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.nav_bar img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  :
}

.scrolled {
  background-color: rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.4);
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.scrolled.nav_bar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.8);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.scrolled.nav_bar .nav_ .item {
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.scrolled.nav_bar .logo {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  ] transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
  <ul class="nav_">


    <li class="item">
      <a href="index.html" class='active-page'>Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>



    <li class="item">
      <a href="work.html">Work</a>
    </li>

    <li class="item">
      <a href="contact.html" class="contact">Contact</a>
    </li>


  </ul>

  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html"> <img class="logo" src="jhlogogrey.png" alt=""> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp

Example:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVUKIW8V3A7V

Answer (score 0):

code a specific screen ratio in CSS, and within that block adjust your container’s position, padding and with.